# Grocery List Add Item

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to write a function which takes two arguments: an array-which is a list of groceries and a single item.

If the single item is not already on the list, then the new item is added to the list.

Function returns the Grocery list

Here is my attempt:

```
var addItem = function(array, a) {    
    if (array.indexOf(a) = -1) {
        array.push(a);
        return array;
    }
    else if (array.indexOf(a) != -1) {
        return array;
    }
};
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? What's the problem you're facing? (Other than the typo in the first `if` assessment...)

Comment: missing a == in if statement, you try to set value to -1, not check if it equals

Comment: Create an addItem function. This function should:
take two arguments:
an item to add to the grocery list
the grocery list (array) to add the item to
only add an item if it doesn’t already exist in the array

Comment: Hi JasonJohnson - if you have a problem, then you need to describe *precisely* where and how your code is going wrong; otherwise it isn't so much a question as you asking strangers to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it basically correct, but missed one `=` in the `if` condition. A single equal sign is a declaration, not a check. And you don't need `else if`, just use `else`. Or even better, remove the whole `else` part, because it is redundant, you will return in any case.

```
var addItem = function(array, a) {    
    if (array.indexOf(a) == -1) { // missing '=' here
        array.push(a);
    }

    return array;
};
```

Working example:

```js
var arr = [];
var addItem = function(array, a) {
    if (array.indexOf(a) == -1) { // missing '=' here
        array.push(a);
    }

    return array;
};

addItem(arr, "test 1");
addItem(arr, "test 1");
addItem(arr, "test 2");

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Create an addItem function. This function should:
take two arguments:
an item to add to the grocery list
the grocery list (array) to add the item to
only add an item if it doesn’t already exist in the array    <<<<this is the problem.   The code doesn't work for some reason  here are two tests
  it("adds an element to the end of the array", function() {
    expect(addItem("banana", ["orange"])).to.eql(["orange", "banana"]);
  });

  it("doesn't add an element if it already exists in the array", function() {
    expect(addItem("orange", ["orange"])).to.eql(["orange"]);
  });

Comment: The code is working. I've made an example. @JasonJohnson

Comment: And your test should be: `expect(addItem(["banana"], "orange")).to.eql(["banana", "orange"]);` and `expect(addItem(["orange"], "orange")).to.eql(["orange"]);` First parameter of `addItem` is the `array`, seconds the `string` to add. @JasonJohnson

Comment: I"m getting this error:          TypeError: array.push is not a function at addItem (decoded.txt:4:15) at Context.<anonymous> (decoded.txt:26:12)

Comment: Yes, look at your tests. `"banana"` is a `string` and not an `array`. You have to pass `["banana"]` in your tests. Read my previous comment. @JasonJohnson

Comment: also this error:    doesn't add an element if it already exists in the array
expected 'orange' to deeply equal [ 'orange' ]

Comment: Please, think about what you do there and don't post comments over and over. I've posted what you did wrong in detail. The problem is not the function, the problem is your incorrect tests. @JasonJohnson

Comment: so i unknowingly ordered the array and single item in teh wrong order (array, a) instead of (a, array).  I don't have any control over how the test is run, so i have to change the code accordingly..  THANK YOU eibehr and everyone else!